# Construction of an unwrapping matrix on Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I need some help, i would like to construct a `B` matrix from a `A` matrix by following these instructions :

1. `A = A0 + A1 + ... + Ak` and `B = [B0 ; B1 ; ... ; Bk]` with `k` an integer ;
2. The size of `A` is : `m * n` and the size of `B` is : `[(1+k)m] * n`;
3. `A0, A1, ...., Ak` has size `m * n`.

Example 1 : Let `A = [3 3]`of size `1 * 2`

- If `k = 1`, `A = A0 + A1 = [2,1] + [1,2]` and `B = [2 1 ; 1 2]` with size`2 * 2`
- If `k = 2`, `A = A0 + A1 + A2 = [1,1] + [1,1] + [1,1]` and `B = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]` with size `3 * 2`
- If `k = 3`, `A = A0 + A1 + A2 + A3 = [1,0] + [0,1] + [1,1] + [1,1]` and `B = [1 0 ; 0 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]` with size `4 * 2`
- ...

Example 2 : Let  `A = [1 2 0 0 0 ; 0 3 1 1 1 ; 0 1 2 1 2]`of size `3 * 5`

- If `k = 1`, `A = A0 + A1 = [1 2 0 0 0 ; 0 1 1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 0 2] + [0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 2 0 0 1 ; 0 1 1 1 0]` and `B = [1 2 0 0 0 ; 0 1 1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 0 2 ; 0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 2 0 0 1 ; 0 1 1 1 0]` with size `6 * 5`

I would like to have the value of matrix `B` for any matrix `A` of dimension `m * n`

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the relation between `Ai`s and the `k`. In your first example, what prevents `A = A0 + A1 = [3,3] + [0,0]` from being a valid result?

Comment: That's true, but the objective here is to decompose the coefficients into smaller coefficients. With the case A = A0 + A1 = [3 , 3] + [0 , 0], we have not changed much in the initial matrix. The k represents the decomposition factors. If k = 6 we will have : A = A0+A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method creates a function called `Decompose_Number()` which breaks the number into an array of integers that sums up to the original number. This is run through each value in the original matrix/vector until all the numbers are decomposed into `k+1` components. Within the `Decompose_Number()` function random numbers that are close to being evenly distributed are created. Pseudo steps that were taken:

• Create a function that can decompose a number into any number of smaller integers.
• Run through each matrix value and store the decomposed result in a larger array.
• Use an iterative approach to creating variables, `A0`, `A1`, ... `Ak` using `assignin()` and `sprintf()` functions

[image: Results]

```
clc;
clear;

k = 1;

%Vector to split into components%
A = [3 3];
A = [1 2 0 0 0 ; 0 3 1 1 1 ; 0 1 2 1 2];


%Decomposition factor%
Decomposition_Factor = k + 1;

[Matrix_Height,Matrix_Width] = size(A);
A_Decomposed = zeros(Matrix_Height,Matrix_Width,Decomposition_Factor);

for Row = 1: Matrix_Height
    for Column = 1: Matrix_Width

    Value = A(Row,Column);
    [Result] = Decompose_Number(Value,Decomposition_Factor);
    A_Decomposed(Row,Column,:) = Result;
    
    end
end

%Creating decomposed A vectors A_1 through A_K
for Vector_Index = 1: Decomposition_Factor
    assignin('base',sprintf("A%d",Vector_Index-1),A_Decomposed(:,:,Vector_Index));
end

[Result_Height,Result_Width,Vector_Number] = size(A_Decomposed);

B = [];
for Merge_Index = 1: Vector_Number
    
    B = [B; A_Decomposed(:,:,Merge_Index)];

end 

fprintf("Resultant Matrix\n");
B 

%*************************************************************************%
%DECOMPOSE NUMBER FUNCTION%
%*************************************************************************%

function [Result] = Decompose_Number(Number,Decomposition_Factor)

Result = zeros(1,Decomposition_Factor);

Equal_Split_Value = Number/Decomposition_Factor;
Equal_Split_Value_Low = floor(Equal_Split_Value);
Equal_Split_Value_High = ceil(Equal_Split_Value);

for Index = 1: Decomposition_Factor-1

Generated_Number = randi([Equal_Split_Value_Low,Equal_Split_Value_High],1,1);
Result(1,Index) = Generated_Number;

while(sum(Result,'all') > Number)
Generated_Number = randi([Equal_Split_Value_Low,Equal_Split_Value_High],1,1);
Result(1,Index) = Generated_Number;
end

if(sum(Result,'all') == Number)
break;
end
  
end

Result(end) = Number - sum(Result,'all'); 
Random_Indexing_Vector = randperm(Decomposition_Factor);
Result = Result(Random_Indexing_Vector);

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**